# Generic convenience init() on a superclass constrained to the subclass of the initialised object?

Tags: swift, swift3

Is it possible to write an initialiser in Swift 3 so that the `T` will be constrained to the type of the created object? (subclass of the class it's defined in)

Something to the effect of

```
// Not real code
extension UIView {
    convenience init<T>(style: (T) -> Void...) where T == self.dynamicType {
        self.init()
        for s in style {
            s(self) 
        }
    }
}

...

let v1 = UIView(style: funcThatAppliesToUIView)
let v2 = UILabel(style: funcThatAppliesToUIView, funcThatAppliesToUILabel)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `self` in generic constraints, however you can use `Self` to constraint by types defined in the extended class/protocol, but using it as it is resolve to the static type you're extending not the dynamic one.(but let's keep it ontopic). Even though if constraining on dynamic type were possible you wont be able to do this:

```
let v2 = UILabel(style: funcThatAppliesToUIView, funcThatAppliesToUILabel)
```

That's because `T` depends on it params, which would be deduced to `UIView` or `UILabel` but the constraint on dynamic type(`UILabel`), will impose just functions that receive `UILabel` and `funcThatAppliesToUIView` wont be accepted.

Comment: I should probably said "instantiated type" (compile time) rather than "dynamic type" (run time). PS The latter is actually not true. `(UIView) -> Void` will convert to `(UILabel) -> Void`, Swift supports type contravariance.

Comment: "instantiated type" is the same as dynamic type, and by that, if he instantiated(dynamic) type were UILabel, you can't pass `(UIView) -> Void`

Comment: Oh yes, you can! `(UIView) -> Void` is a subtype of `(UILabel) -> Void` due to contravariance.

Comment: As matter of fact, you were right, I was missing the point of contravariance. without dynamic restriction the function will accept every kind of view functions. e.g UIButton functions when the dynamic type is a UILabel, if you find a solution to restrict up to dynamic type, share it with me. :)